# WM_CLOSE is not closing the application. Application is hanging. Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

We see that the application hangs when trying to close the application by sending WM_CLOSE to all the windows in that application. Note that WM_CLOSE is sent by a different application. We are using EnumChildWindows to enumerate through all windows and match the process id of the window handle with the process id of the application that needs to closed using GetWindowThreadProcessId method and send WM_CLOSE to all the windows of that process. From the dump, we see that the process is waiting on some handles. However we are not sure which handle the process is waiting on.

Call Stack:

> ntdll.dll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects()   Unknown
> KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()   Unknown
> KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForMultipleObjects()    Unknown
> CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::MessageSession::WaitOnHandleCollection(struct Microsoft::CoreUI::Support::Win32Handle *,unsigned int)   Unknown
> CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::MessageSession::ProcessPendingAlpcConnections() Unknown
> CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::MessageSession::OnFinalRelease()    Unknown
> CoreMessaging.dll!Cn::Com::ExportAdapter::Destroy(void) Unknown
> CoreMessaging.dll!Cn::Com::ExportAdapter::Release() Unknown
> TextInputFramework.dll!CTextInputClientFreeThread::~CTextInputClientFreeThread(void)    Unknown
> TextInputFramework.dll!CTextInputClientFreeThread::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)   Unknown TextInputFramework.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Details::RuntimeClassImpl<struct Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,1,0,0,struct ITextInputClient,struct IRemoteTextInputClient,struct IInputLanguageProvider,struct IKeyEventProcessor,struct IMessageProxyReconnectAdapterOwner,struct ITextInputClientInternal,struct IConnectionMonitor>::Release(void)    Unknown msctf.dll!CTextInputClientWrapper::~CTextInputClientWrapper(void)   Unknown msctf.dll!CTextInputClientWrapper::Release()    Unknown msctf.dll!ATL::AtlComPtrAssign(struct IUnknown * *,struct IUnknown *)   Unknown msctf.dll!OnTextInputClientWrapperReleased(void)    Unknown msctf.dll!CTextInputClientWrapper::Release()    Unknown TextInputFramework.dll!Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<struct IInputLanguageProvider>::InternalRelease(void) Unknown TextInputFramework.dll!TextInputHost::~TextInputHost()  Unknown TextInputFramework.dll!TextInputHost::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)    Unknown
> TextInputFramework.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Details::RuntimeClassImpl<struct Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags<2>,1,0,0,struct IRemoteTextInputHost,struct ITextInputHost,struct IMessageProxyReconnectAdapterOwner,struct IMessageProxyListener>::Release(void) Unknown
> msctf.dll!ATL::AtlComPtrAssign(struct IUnknown * *,struct IUnknown *)   Unknown
> msctf.dll!CThreadInputMgr::Suspend()    Unknown
> msctf.dll!CThreadInputMgr::OnActivationChange() Unknown
> msctf.dll!CThreadInputMgr::Deactivate() Unknown
> msctf.dll!CicBridge::DeactivateIMMX()   Unknown
> msctf.dll!_CtfImeDestroyThreadMgr() Unknown
> msctf.dll!CtfImeDestroyThreadMgr() Unknown
> imm32.dll!ActivateOrDeactivateTIM() Unknown
> msctf.dll!TF_Notify()   Unknown
> user32.dll!CtfHookProcWorker(int,unsigned __int64,__int64,unsigned __int64) Unknown
> user32.dll!CallHookWithSEH(struct _GENERICHOOKHEADER *,void *,unsigned long *,unsigned __int64) Unknown
> user32.dll!**fnHkINDWORD() Unknown
> ntdll.dll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue()   Unknown
> win32u.dll!NtUserMessageCall() Unknown
> user32.dll!RealDefWindowProcWorker()    Unknown
> user32.dll!DefWindowProcW() Unknown
> user32.dll!ImeWndProcWorker()   Unknown
> user32.dll!ImeWndProcW(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)   Unknown
> user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
> user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown

Any idea how to debug the issue ? Or any logging that could help identify the problem ?

Comment: Unless you wrote all of the applications you're closing down, there is no guarantee that `WM_CLOSE` shuts down an application.  Even the **Remarks** section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) explains this.

Comment: To automate another application, use UI Automation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32 . To close it, get for example its main Window's window pattern: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-controlpatternsoverview and call its Close method https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-implementingwindow you'll have to handle possible confirm message boxes with the same techniques. You can try all that beforehand using the Inspect tool from SDK https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects

Answer (score 2):

First, strictly speaking sending a `WM_CLOSE` message to a window doesn't necessarily destroy it. This message is handled by the appropriate handler (window proc), and it *may*, but doesn't have to decide to destroy it.

Second, do NOT try to destroy child windows created by an application. It may not expect this, and may not work properly (may crash). You should only destroy the top-level window.

And last, but not least, sending a message to a window belonging to another thread (and another process in your case) will **BLOCK** your thread, until that thread that handles messages for that window processes it. If that thread decides not to process messages at all, then you will be blocked forever.
In addition if that thread waits for yours (for instance, it could also send a message to your thread) - then you have a deadlock.

If your goal is to "ask" another application to close, then a conventional way to do this is to find the target thread (what you already did), and then post (not send!!!) a `WM_QUIT` message to it.
That is, call `PostThreadMessage` with `uMsg == WM_QUIT`. But note: the target application *may*, but strictly speaking doesn't have to, quit.

Comment: *"In addition if that thread waits for yours (for instance, it could also send a message to your thread) - then you have a deadlock."* - No, that's not how the system works. `SendMessage` dispatches [inbound cross-thread sent messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983). The deadlock scenario you describe cannot happen.

Comment: @IInspectable: didn't know that, thanks. So while you're in `SendMessage` you're actually in a (sort of) message loop, not a dead sleep. Makes sense. But it's still easy to  fall into a deadlock if sending messages synchronously to another thread without thinking (or knowing) what it's doing.

Comment: Indeed, though the solution isn't `PostThreadMessage`, it's [`SendMessageTimeoutW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeoutw).

Comment: @IInspectable: don't mean to be pedantic, but it's not a good solution either. You don't want to be blocked (though with timeout, but still), neither sending `WM_CLOSE` to a window is a good idea. It's just not the way to do this.

Comment: Would you rather be blocked for a client-decided timeout, or have the target potentially miss the message altogether? `PostThreadMessage` is the tool to make sure the latter is [real](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553).

Comment: yes, it's a known problem with implicit message loops (i.e. modal dialog, message box, popup menu, etc.), posting `WM_QUIT` will be "eaten" by them. But you can also post `WM_CLOSE` instead of sending it. Anyway I'm personally strongly against sending messages to a window of unknown application. Depending on timeouts - It's just incorrect design.

Comment: Just because you are against sending messages to random windows doesn't mean that if you do decide to do so, you shouldn't use the right tool. That tool is `SendMessageTimeout`. It's not `SendMessage`, nor `PostMessage`, nor `PostThreadMessage`.

Comment: @IInspectable: and why `SendMessageTimeout` is the correct tool? Why not `PostMessage`? Why it must be synchronous in your opinion? Could you clarify please?

Comment: In this case, the sender wants to know, whether the message was actually handled. Hence, `PostMessage` cannot be used.